# MongoDB $or vs $match on aggregate with lots of date comparisons

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need to count all bookings that occurs in April along with the amount of booked days in April.
The only way I know how to do this is to make 4 different MongoDB lookups and loop thru each one and count manually in JS
(selectBooking is the result from mongoDB, for now I just find all bookings in the database, but that is really slow!)

So my question is - can this be done in a smarter way?

```
var startOfMonth = new Date("2017-04-01 00:00:00") / 1000;
var endOfMonth = new Date("2017-04-30 23:23:59") / 1000;

// If booking is INSIDE this month 
//    [ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo]  <-- This month 
//           [xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx]        <-- The booking
var selectBooking = bookingArray.filter(function(obj){
    return (obj.checkin >= startOfMonth && obj.checkout <= endOfMonth)
})
for (var b=0; b<selectBooking.length; b++) {    
    totalBookings++;
    totalDays += daysBetween(new Date(selectBooking[b].checkin*1000),new Date(selectBooking[b].checkout*1000))
}

// If booking COVERS the whole month
//    [oooooooooooooooooooooooooooo]    <-- This month 
// [xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx] <-- The booking
var selectBooking = bookingArray.filter(function(obj){
    return (obj.checkin < startOfMonth && obj.checkout > endOfMonth)
})
for (var b=0; b<selectBooking.length; b++) {    
    totalBookings++;
    totalDays += daysBetween(new Date(startOfMonth*1000),new Date(endOfMonth*1000))
}

// If booking is BEGINNING before this month but ENDING in this month
//       [ooooooooooooooooooooooooooo]  <-- This month 
// [xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx]                   <-- The booking
var selectBooking = bookingArray.filter(function(obj){
    return (obj.checkin < startOfMonth && obj.checkout > startOfMonth)
})
for (var b=0; b<selectBooking.length; b++) {    
    totalBookings++;
    totalDays += daysBetween(new Date(startOfMonth*1000),new Date(selectBooking[b].checkout*1000))
}

// If booking is BEGINING in this month but ENDING after this month
//   [ooooooooooooooooooooooooooo]      <-- This month 
//                   [xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx] <-- The booking
var selectBooking = bookingArray.filter(function(obj){
    return (obj.checkin < endOfMonth && obj.checkout > endOfMonth)
})
for (var b=0; b<selectBooking.length; b++) {    
    totalBookings++;
    totalDays += daysBetween(new Date(selectBooking[b].checkin*1000),new Date(endOfMonth*1000))
}
```

I tried this, but get error:
"the match filter must be an expression in an object"

```
db.getCollection("booking").aggregate([
    { $match: 
        [
            { checkin: {$gte: 1490979600}, checkout: {$lte: 1493569439} },
            { checkin: {$lt:  1490979600}, checkout: {$gt:  1493569439} },
            { checkin: {$lt:  1490979600}, checkout: {$gt:  1490979600} },
            { checkin: {$lt:  1493569439}, checkout: {$gt:  1493569439} }
        ]
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "_id" : 0,
            "checkin" : 1,
            "checkout" : 1
        }
    }   
])
```

I also tried this, but get error:
"Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$or'"

```
db.getCollection("booking").aggregate([
    { $or: 
        [
            { checkin: {$gte: 1490979600}, checkout: {$lte: 1493569439} },
            { checkin: {$lt:  1490979600}, checkout: {$gt:  1493569439} },
            { checkin: {$lt:  1490979600}, checkout: {$gt:  1490979600} },
            { checkin: {$lt:  1493569439}, checkout: {$gt:  1493569439} }
        ]
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "_id" : 0,
            "checkin" : 1,
            "checkout" : 1
        }
    }   
])
```

I use this a LOT in our reports. 
With bookings (like here), with expenses, with invoices etc etc....
I do them all in the same crappy slow way.

Here is hoping someone out there can figure out a better way :-)

(sorry for the long post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use $match with $or like below

```
db.getCollection("booking").aggregate([
    {
        $match:
        { 
            $or: 
            [
                { checkin: {$gte: 1490979600}, checkout: {$lte: 1493569439} },
                { checkin: {$lt:  1490979600}, checkout: {$gt:  1493569439} },
                { checkin: {$lt:  1490979600}, checkout: {$gt:  1490979600} },
                { checkin: {$lt:  1493569439}, checkout: {$gt:  1493569439} }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "_id" : 0,
            "checkin" : 1,
            "checkout" : 1
        }
    }   
])
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I got the full list only containing the relevant bookings. One more question, I still need to do the four js loops on the result in order to count the amount of booked days right?  Or do you have an idea how that can be done smarter?